# trigger jquery floatlabels plugin on input load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use jquery [floatlabels](https://github.com/clubdesign/floatlabels.js/blob/master/floatlabels.js) plugin to create inline labels for input fields in the form.

It works great for fields that don't have text in them but I need to have the label even if there is a pre-defaulted text in them. I checked the plugin code and found this line

```
thisElement.on('keyup blur change', function( e ) {
                self.checkValue( e );
            });
```

Which means that this will only be triggered on keyup, blur and change events. I need this to trigger even when the input is loaded for the first time. I know I have to do something like

***checkValue for everyfield and if there is already value then self.showLabel***

But I am not exactly sure how ??

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried jQuery load event - http://api.jquery.com/load-event/? Can you update the plugin's code?

Comment: yes, I can update the plugin code

Comment: See my answer below. checkValue() already has some verification of whether there is some value in element or not. So it possibly would work with even this small change (needs verification though).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can update that plugin's code, you can try something like this:

```
thisElement.on('load keyup blur change', function( e ) {
    self.checkValue( e );
});
```

Comment: No, load doesn't make any difference. I tried using console.log inside the on event. I doesn't get triggered when form is loaded for the first time.

Comment: My bad, this event works differently than I expected. Anyway, according to plugin code, it calls this.checkValue(); when initialized. Have you tried adding a breakpoint inside checkValue() and see whether it's called on page load and (if it is) what are the values of thisElement.data('flout') and currentFlout?

Comment: Since checkValue is being called without any arguments therefore the currentFlout comes as undefined

Comment: Since this condition should be true: thisElement.val() !== "", then thisElement.data('flout') should become 1, and then this condition: thisElement.data('flout') === '1' && currentFlout !== '1' should be true, which calls this.showLabel(), right?

Comment: llya you were right. I checked again after you pointed out about code. It seems the issue was with the API from which I was calling the plugin intialization. At point form was empty and only in a later event it was populated. Moving the code to that protion solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your valuable input

Comment: Well you did point out the problem unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as the right answer. Thanks again